# UIScrollView contentOffset

Tags: iphone

i have done a simple scroll test and logged contentOffset in the scrollViewDidScroll delegate. If i scroll fast i got crazy offsets

336
53
360
44
406
26
...
the if the decrementing value reaches 0 it is always incrementing...

If i am scrolling to the right i would await incrementing values ONLY and not alternating ones for the first ones - is this a known bug or a feature?

Answer (score 2):

You do know that contentOffset is a CGPoint, right?  You have an x and a y coordinate value there.